# Model.create retrive how many documents have been created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, bulkinsert

I am using Model.create(Array) in Mongoose.
I want to provide user a feedback about how many documents have been created and how many of them haven't (i.e. they didn't validate).
I created a callback like this

```
User.create(usersToImport, function(err, docs) {  
    console.log(err);
    console.log(docs);
}
```

The problem is that if any document does not validate, I only receive a validation error on the single non-valid document, while I cannot retrieve any information about the inserted documents.
Is there any way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need something like [`.settle()` method](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#whensettle) from [`when.js` module](https://github.com/cujojs/when).

Here is an example of doing it using `when.js` with `mongoose 3.8.x`:

```
when = require('when');

promises = usersToImport.map(function(user) {
  return User.create(user); // returns Promise
});
when.settle(promises).then(function(results) {
  // results is an array, containing following elements:
  //   { state: 'fulfilled', value: <document> }
  //   { state: 'rejected', value: <error> }
});
```

It's possible to do it without Promises (e.g. using [`async` module](https://github.com/caolan/async)), but the code will be much more complicated.

Comment: Interesting. I knew `async` but I didn't know `when.js`. I'll give it a try and see if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Model.create()` isn't going to return that information for you. The best option would be to roll your own version of `Model.create()`, which is essentially a convenience method for calling `Model.save()` multiple times, and collate the information yourself. A good way to get started is the code for [`Model.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create).

Comment: Yes, I know `Model.create` is just a wrapper for `Model.save`. I'll check the code and see if it could be useful.